# chrome device inspector stopped working

Tags: android, google-chrome-devtools, device

I was able to inspect and interact with (update css) on my android devices using chrome's device inspector then a week or so ago it stopped working. I can still see and interact with devices somewhat, but the styles pane never changes to reflect the element I have selected, and selecting elements is more difficult. Use to be a single click, now its a double click and even that doesn't always work - and when it does finally work, the styles pane still doesn't display the attributes of the element I've just selected, just stays at the root of the document from when page initially loaded - so I can't edit DOM properties as I was able to do.

I've deleted Canary and re-installed, but still have this issue. Has anyone seen this before and found a solution?